# Why does C++ has an additional class name declaration?

Tags: c++

why do we have to declarer a class name in `C++` like:

```
class MDT_DECL Transfer{
    // declaration goes here
};
```

? What's the reason for the `<DIRNAME>_DECL`? I see it's especially used when the code needs to be compiled in `Windows`

Comment: What is `MDT_DECL` defined as? It's surely just a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to. But in windows you have to explicitly state you want the class to export symbols with `_declspec(dllexport)` (which is probably what that macro expands to).